# gammu-smsd RunOnReceive script results exit status 2

Tags: linux, bash, sms, file-permissions, gammu

I want to forward an SMS using gammu-smsd RunOnReceive.

**That is the script I want to run** (/var/spool/gammu/forward.sh) and it goes perfectly if I run it from a sudoer or using `sudo -u gammu -g gammu /var/spool/gammu/forward.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

SMS_MESSAGES=1

for i in `seq $SMS_MESSAGES`
do
    number="SMS_${i}_NUMBER"
    text="SMS_${i}_TEXT"
    eval "gammu-smsd-inject TEXT my_number_goes_here -text \"${!number}: ${!text}\""
done
```

**And here is the problem I am experiencing:**

```
Thu 2015/01/29 23:08:57 gammu-smsd[2549]: Starting run on receive: /var/spool/gammu/forward.sh IN20150130_000850_00_+37368214400_00.txt 
Thu 2015/01/29 23:08:57 gammu-smsd[2154]: Process failed with exit status 2
```

**Output of `ls -l /etc/gammu-smsdrc /var/spool/gammu/ /usr/bin/gammu-smsd*`**:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   457 Jan 29 22:44 /etc/gammu-smsdrc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14336 Jun 10  2012 /usr/bin/gammu-smsd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51164 Jun 10  2012 /usr/bin/gammu-smsd-inject
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9972 Jun 10  2012 /usr/bin/gammu-smsd-monitor

/var/spool/gammu/:
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 2 gammu gammu 4096 Jan 28 16:02 error
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gammu gammu  189 Jan 29 22:13 forward.sh
drwxrwxrwx 2 gammu gammu 4096 Jan 29 23:08 inbox
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gammu gammu 3702 Jan 29 23:08 log
drwxrwxrwx 2 gammu gammu 4096 Jan 29 23:07 outbox
drwxrwxrwx 2 gammu gammu 4096 Jan 29 23:07 sent
```

**What happens if I just do `./forward.sh` (not root) - so all is OK:**

```
gammu-smsd-inject[2606]: Created outbox message OUTC20150029_231213_00_my_number_here_sms0.txt
Written message with ID /var/spool/gammu/outbox/OUTC20150029_231213_00_my_number_here_sms0.txt
```

**Here is my /etc/gammu-smsdrc**

```
# Configuration file for Gammu SMS Daemon

[gammu]
port = /dev/ttyUSB0
connection = at

[smsd]
service = files

logfile = /var/spool/gammu/log

debuglevel = 2

commtimeout = 1
sendtimeout = 15
statusfrequency = 0

outboxformat = unicode
transmitformat = unicode

RunOnReceive = /var/spool/gammu/forward.sh

inboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/inbox/
outboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/outbox/
sentsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/sent/
errorsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/error/
```

`ps -fe | grep gammu`:

```
gammu     2154     1  0 23:05 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/gammu-smsd --daemon --user gammu --pid /var/run/gammu-smsd.pid
cubie     2644  2403  0 23:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep gammu
```

Please, help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it this way:

1. First add gammu user to sudoers, with no password:

   type:   `$ sudo visudo`

and add: `gammu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

2. Then run gammu-smsd as root user:

in `/etc/init.d/gammu-smsd`

change `USER=gammu` to `USER=root`

save it and don't forget to restart daemon: `service gammu-smsd restart`

3. In *RunOnReceive* script add `sudo` in front of `gammu-smsd-inject`:

   e.g.: `sudo gammu-smsd-inject TEXT my_tel_num -text "Hello world!"`

I hope this will work for you too!

P.S.: I use Gammu version 1.31.90.

Comment: Very insecure, but still a solution. Hope somebody will solve their problem, but for me it's not an option. I just made a cronscript from root, which runs every minute. It takes all messages from inbox and sends their content to a given number.